# vgamepad PS4 controller emulation issue

Tags: python, gamepad

Using vgamepad for PS4 controller emulation, the virtual gamepad isn't responding to button presses. Initialization, button constants, and regular updates are in place. No errors reported. Any common pitfalls or suggestions for troubleshooting?

```
import vgamepad as vg
gamepad = vg.VDS4Gamepad()
if joystick.get_button(0):
    gamepad.press_button(vg.DS4_BUTTONS.DS4_BUTTON_CROSS)
else:
    gamepad.release_button(vg.DS4_BUTTONS.DS4_BUTTON_CROSS)
```

*Edit:*

I noticed that `gamepad.press_button(vg.XUSB_BUTTON.XUSB_GAMEPAD_RIGHT_THUMB)` emulates the triangle button but not the others.

Comment: XUSB_GAMEPAD_RIGHT_THUMB and DS4_BUTTON_TRIANGLE have the same value so this seems to be working correctly. Are you calling gamepad.update() after changing the button state?